# Java BLE / Bluetooth smart libraries

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, desktop

I'm attempting to write a desktop application that connects to bluetooth smart / BLE devices, for example, Polar Heart monitor.

Is there a generally recognised way to do this, Java API or library?

This is for a desktop application not android.  Everything I see online is year(s) out of date or specifically android.  I would rather try to avoid writing some platform specific JNI shenanigans.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using a linux based system you can use bluez5.

Bluez5 exposes interfaces in the DBus thus interaction with bluez can be done with the dbus bindings of your choice(C, python, C#Mono.. ). Using the dbus-api you'll be able to scan, connect, pair, notify, read/write, advertise and much more

You can find a description of the dbus api exposed by bluez here (I suggest looking at the adapter-api, device-api and gatt-api) : https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

Before diving into the code you can play around with bluetoothctl (a tool that you can use for pairing, connecting, services discovery, gatt attributes reading & writing etc).
Also, you can find the source code of bluetoothctl  here : https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/client/main.c

bluetoothctl was built using GLib GDBus (dbus bindings for Glib in C) and you will find code examples for pretty much everything you'd like to do with bluez.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [NRJSerial](https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial) in a desktop application (Linux based) with Java.  It has native in it but I didn't have to deal with that directly. There are ways to read from the USB/Serial port in Java but I found this to be portable and easy.

A word of warning though - it's low level.  I was dealing with a PulseOximeter that just dumped binary so it wasn't too bad.  If you start to get into GATT and so on it will be a decent amount of work to handle that.